# JavaScript Loop and wait for function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, loops

I have a simple single-dimension array, let's say:

```
fruits = ["apples","bananas","oranges","peaches","plums"];
```

I can loop through with with `$.each()` function:

```
$.each(fruits, function(index, fruit) {  
   showFruit(fruit);
});
```

but I'm calling another function which I need to finish before moving on to the next item.

So, if I have a function like this:

```
function showFruit(fruit){
    $.getScript('some/script.js',function(){
        // Do stuff
    })
}
```

What's the best way to make sure the previous fruit has been appended before moving on?

Comment: Array: `fruits = []`. What you have is an object. Just an FYI.

Comment: @ahren That's not an object, that's a syntax error ;)

Comment: But your code does not have the behavior that you are expecting?

Comment: Sorry, too much JSON lately, the code I'm using works fine, it just causes errors because it can't finish the previous function call.

Comment: Let me guess, `#some_div` doesn't exist in the DOM when you call `showFruit`, and you're wondering why none of the elements are showing up.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want one fruit to be appended before you load the next one, then you cannot structure your code the way you have.  That's because with asynchronous functions like `$.getScript()`, there is no way to make it wait until done before execution continues.  It is possible to use a `$.ajax()` and set that to synchronous, but that is bad for the browser (it locks up the browser during the networking) so it is not recommended.

Instead, you need to restructure your code to work asynchronously which means you can't use a traditional `for` or `.each()` loop because they don't iterate asynchronously.

```
var fruits = ["apples","bananas","oranges","peaches","plums"];

(function() {
    var index = 0;

    function loadFruit() {
        if (index < fruits.length) {
            var fruitToLoad = fruits[index];
            $.getScript('some/script.js',function(){
                // Do stuff
                ++index;
                loadFruit();
            });
        }
    }
    loadFruit();

})();
```

In ES7 (or when transpiling ES7 code), you can also use `async` and `await` like this:

```
var fruits = ["apples","bananas","oranges","peaches","plums"];

(async function() {
    for (let fruitToLoad of fruits) {
        let s = await $.getScript('some/script.js');
        // do something with s and with fruitToLoad here
    }

})();
```

Comment: Much better answer than mine — it helps to know jQuery.

Comment: `fruits[i];` should be `fruits[index];` Last second variable name change I'd assume. :-) I tried to edit, but not enough characters in the change.

Comment: Added an ES7 example with `async/await`.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript in browsers is single-threaded.  It will not continue until the function it called returns.  You don't need to check.

Comment: ... unless the function is asynchronous. But this isn't the case in the example.

Comment: The function I'm calling calls other scripts, and it appears that the dynamic loading of those scripts is not stopping the next loop to proceed

Comment: @Fluidbyte, you need to make a reduced test case

Comment: Yes, please give us the simplest version you can that _doesn't_ work.

Comment: You want all 200 lines of code that's ultimately behind this thing?

Comment: @Fluidbyte: the _simplest_ version that doesn't work.  Besides, if you haven't yet tried cutting things out to narrow down what isn't working, you're depriving yourself of a very good approach to solving your problem.

Comment: `$.getScript()` and its associated completion callback is asynchronous so this answer is not correct for this particular question.

Comment: @JasonFruit, I've been cutting out peices and have it down to the core. Looks like the issue is synchronous v. asynchronous.