# How to loop an array with jquery in sequence

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, sequential

i've been searching, trying and i'm now hitting my head against the wall! Sounds like something simple but can't get ahead of it! Tried .each, .map, deferred, promise and some others but nothing worked.

So i thought i could ask here:
For each element in an array, i need to call a function, wait for it to complete, move to next element and call the same function again.

```js
function del(value) {
  //do some stuff taking random time
  console.log(value);
}

function asd() {
  var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
  $.each(arr, function(key, value) {
    del(value);
  });
}

$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    asd();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">test</a>
```

I wanna make sure i get "one", "two", "three", "four" in the right order. At the moment i sometimes get "three", "one", "two", "four"!

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: if the values in `arr` is in the proper order, you will always get the proper order

Comment: I think the question is how to wait for `del()` to complete before moving on to the next iteration

Comment: yep @Pete, i may not have been clear enough... i need to wait for each del() call to complete before calling it again

Comment: @Gotrekk you would have to restructure the way you call del so it is only called after the function has completed - [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12359450/javascript-loop-and-wait-for-function) it may give you an idea of how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not the loop or order of the array it s the `//do some stuff taking random time` I am assuming it is an async call most likely a ajax call. I handle this situation with the below code;

```
var arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
function del(arrayParam) {
   var item = arrayParam.shift(); //gets first item and removes it from the array 
   if (item) {
      $(/*your ajax call*/).success(function() { 
              del(arrayParam); /*re call function*/ 
          });
   }
   else {
      // you are don with the array show message/alert etc
   }
}
// and some how call the first call might be a button click etc.
del(arrayParam);
```

Comment: this feels like a good solution. Adapating my code for it. will let you know :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by calling the function on page load otherwise there's no event to call the function. I think this is what you were asking for, yes?

```
(function() {
$("a").click(function() {
    //console.log("test: I'm inside");
    asd();
});
}) ();
```